# How do you perform a ContentSearch using the "MoreLikeThis" handler?

Tags: content-search, solr

We have a Solr index and using the standard Linq queries.

I noticed that Sitecore supports Solr features like `Suggester` or `Highlighter`, but I did not find anything about **MoreLikeThis** feature.

I'm interested to see how I can use the "MoreLikeThis" solr handler in Sitecore. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Sitecore 9` has an OOTB extension **GetMoreLikeThis** for the `IProviderSearchContext`. To use it you need to install the `SolrNet` nuget package. You can use it like following:

```
var contextIndex = _contextRepository.GetSearchIndexContext("search_index");
using (var context = contextIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var parameters = new MoreLikeThisHandlerParameters(new[] {"field1", "field2"})
    {
        MinDocFreq = 1, // minimum document frequency
        MinTermFreq = 1, // minimum term frequency
    };

    var query = SolrMLTQuery.FromQuery(new SolrQuery("search_term"));
    var queryOption = new MoreLikeThisHandlerQueryOptions(parameters);
    var results = context.GetMoreLikeThis<SearchResultItem>(query, queryOption);

    var interestingTerms = results.InterestingTerms;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a native `SorlNet` query:

```
var contextIndex = _contextRepository.GetSearchIndexContext("search_index");
using (var context = contextIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var results = context.Query<SearchResultItem>(new SolrQuery("search_term"), new QueryOptions
    {
        MoreLikeThis = new MoreLikeThisParameters(new[] { "field1", "field2" })
        {
            MinDocFreq = 1, // minimum document frequency
            MinTermFreq = 1, // minimum term frequency
        },
    });

    var similarResults = results.SimilarResults;
}
```

If you use `LINQ`-based predicates and they are complex and you can not rewrite your queries to `SolrNet`-based, you can use this *"hack"* to convert them. But keep in mind that in this case one additional request will be sent to Solr:

```
var linqQuery = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate);
var solrNetQuery = new SolrQuery(((IHasNativeQuery)linqQuery).Query.ToString());
```

Comment: Can I use the same nuget package in Sitecore 8.2?

Comment: Sure, the default Sitecore installation includes a default implementation of the Solr connector (SolrNet.dll exists in crear sitecore 8.2 installation). Just make sure that you install corresponding version of SolrNet (the same that sitecore 8.2 uses). These links can be helpful https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html,  https://www.slideshare.net/AninditaBhattacharya4/content-search-api-in-sitecore-81